# React: State is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is currently wrong something with my code, can anyone help?

```
  const {data: coinsList, isFetching} = useGetCoinsQuery();
  const coinsData = coinsList?.data?.coins
  console.log(coinsData)
```

When I `console.log()` the data I can see it in the browser but when I put it in a state like
this:

```
const [coins, setCoins] = useState(coinsData) console.log(coins)
```

I can't
see the data, it returns undefined, can someone explain whats wrong?

I also tried to set the state after:

```
const [coins, setCoins] = useState([])
setCoins(coinsData)
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to store that value in a state?

Answer (score 0):

```
When Coinlist is change then useEffect hook is called and save the value 
coins.


const {data: coinsList, isFetching} = useGetCoinsQuery();
const coinsData = coinsList?.data?.coins
console.log(coinsData)
const [coins, setCoins] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
   setCoins(coinsData)
 },[coinsData])
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much it worked, I'm new to react so this helped a lot 

Comment: Welcome Brother . Have you any question in this code comment here ?

Comment: no, this code is fine, but when I try to map over them like this: it return cant map over undefined

`   {coins.map((coin) => (
                <div className='coin-card'>
                   <p> {coin.id} </p>
                </div>
              ))}  `

Comment: What is the problem here ?

Comment: i don't know there shouldn't be an error here I send you two images above where you can see the component and the error

Comment: {coins && coins.length > 0 &&coins.map((coin) => ( <div className='coin-card'> <p> {coin.id} </p> </div> ))}

I think it will be work

Comment: yes it worked thank you very much I appreciate it  

Comment: Welcome brother .